# Python most efficient data structure to hold values and check if a value exist

Tags: python

Say I have millions of string IDs, I want to store them in a variable and check if one ID exists,  there are both ways I can think of, `list` and `dict`:

Using `list`

```
>>> timeit_a = timeit.Timer('"9999999" in a', setup='a = [str(i) for i in range(3000000)]')
>>> timeit_a.timeit(1)
0.06293477199994868
```

Using `dict`

```
>>> timeit_b = timeit.Timer('"9999999" in b', setup='b = {str(i): None for i in range(3000000)}')
>>> timeit_b.timeit(1)
3.860999981952773e-06  # equal to 0.00000386099
```

As we can see using `dict` is much much much faster, but I feel creating the `dict` with bunch of `None`s for the sake of just utilizing the hashmap of keys is not very elegant.

Is there a more canonical and more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Thanks the the dup suggestion, for the life of me couldn't find that post.

Comment: Yes, use a `set` would be the canonical way of doing this (which is implemented as a hash-set underneath the hood)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have no values, use a `set()`, not a dict

```
{str(i) for i in range(30000)}
```

If you have millions of items, though, maybe offloading to Redis, for example, would be better for an application's memory usage / performance perspective

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Never thought of that!

Comment: I'd suggest an actual `set` comprehension, not `set()` constructor around a generator expression. `{str(i) for i in range(30000)}` will run faster (it avoids the overhead of saving and restoring generator state on yield). `set(map(str, range(30000)))` is probably faster than that, but best not to encourage `map` for trivial gains (it only gives gains in special cases; it's a pessimization any time you have to use a `lambda` that a comprehension could inline).

Answer (score 4):

Definitely use a `set`. It is like a `dict`, but without the values, as it is not a mapping but a... set, surprisingly enough.

```
a = {str(i) for i in range(300000)} # one way of initializing a set
a = set()
for i in range(3000000):
    a.add(str(i)) # another way
```

Comment: `set`s don't have an `append` method. Presumably you meant `add`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger definitely, thx, fixed

Answer (score 1):

You want a `set`.  A set is basically a `dict` with no values.  It's a collection of items with the performance of a `dict` lookup for asking if something is in the set.

```
timeit_b = timeit.Timer('"9999999" in b', setup='b = {str(i) for i in list(range(3000000))}')
timeit_b.timeit(1)
```